# Lock a Button With timer displayed on the button in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-button, rewardedvideoad

I am Working on a android app in which I am displaying a rewarded video ad and want that button to be locked for 10 minutes, I want a timer to be displayed on button after one uses it, here is my java file

```
watch_video_buuton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(Home_page.this,"Please tap more times to load the ad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
        else {
                loadRewardedVideoAd();
       }

    }
 });


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

    loadRewardedVideoAd();

}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

    Toast.makeText(Home_page.this,"Congratulations, you will get 1000 points next time you open the app ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

    int n =  myIntValue+1000;
    editor.putInt("your_int_key", n);
    editor.commit();
    user_id_child.child("scores").setValue(+n);

}
```

Comment: Hi @dhruv bhati and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get an answer to your questions faster, it would be helpful to include a couple things in your answer. It's very good that you gave us your code so far. In addition, could you tell us what you've tried to solve your problem, and why it didn't work?

Comment: Also: I'm gonna suggest an edit to your post to remove some of the tags. In general, tags on Stack Overflow should related to what you're asking about directly. E.g. the "Eclipse" tage should only be put on questions asking *about* Eclipse, not any time the work you're having trouble with is being done in Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bellow code for your button:

```
public void button_OnClick(View view) {
    Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setEnabled(false);

    final long startTime= Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
    final Timer timer=new Timer();
    final Activity activity = this;
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long curentTime=Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
            long elapsedTime=curentTime-startTime;
            ToastTime(10*60*1000, elapsedTime);
            if(curentTime-startTime>=10*60*1000){  //10 minutes in millisecond
                timer.cancel();
                EnableButton();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 500, 2000);
}
```

Where

```
private void ToastTime(long totalTime, long elapsedTime){
    final int remainInSec = (int)(totalTime - elapsedTime) / 1000;
    if(remainInSec>0) {
        final Activity activity = this;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(remainInSec) + " seconds to enable button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void EnableButton(){
    Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Or for simplify:

```
public void button_OnClick(View view) {
    final Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setEnabled(false);

    final long startTime= Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
    final Timer timer=new Timer();
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long curentTime=Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
            long elapsedTime=curentTime-startTime;
            ToastTime(10*60*1000, elapsedTime);
            if(curentTime-startTime>=10*60*1000){  //10 minutes in millisecond
                timer.cancel();
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 500, 2000);
}

private void ToastTime(long totalTime, long elapsedTime){
    final int remainInSec = (int)(totalTime - elapsedTime) / 1000;
    if(remainInSec>0) {
        final Activity activity = this;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(remainInSec) + " seconds to enable button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***Edit***

If you have `many run on main thread` error, try this:
Declare a global variable:

```
boolean isLooperCalled;
```

Now use this:

```
public void button_OnClick(View view) {
    final Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setEnabled(false);

    isLooperCalled=false;   //It's new
    final long startTime= Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
    final Timer timer=new Timer();
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isLooperCalled==false){   //It's new
                Looper.prepare();
                isLooperCalled=true;
            }
            long curentTime=Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
            long elapsedTime=curentTime-startTime;
            ToastTime(10*60*1000, elapsedTime);
            if(curentTime-startTime>=10*60*1000){  //10 minutes in millisecond
                timer.cancel();
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 500, 2000);
}

private void ToastTime(long totalTime, long elapsedTime){
    final int remainInSec = (int)(totalTime - elapsedTime) / 1000;
    if(remainInSec>0) {   //It's edited
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(remainInSec) + " seconds to enable button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If error is persist, Increase time step in `timer.schedule(task, 500, 2000)` from `2000` to `5000` of `10000` (5 sec. or 10 sec.).

Comment: i want to display a toast of the time remaing to unlock that button

Comment: Thank you , this is what i was looking for

Comment: hey , i just used this in my app and i saw that whenever the time completes the app crashes and gets closed , the toast is showed properly but when the time completes the app crashes and says "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: please help me brother , it shows error when time completes that the application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Comment: please , need help fast

Comment: Sorry for late. I edited it again. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: thanks , i apreciated that you have tried to solve my problem , but i am still getting the same error , i putted this when the user gets rewarded in rewarded video ads but still shows same error

Comment: Thanks. Did increasing time step fail to solve the problem?